# Expected value integral when variable in integrand is logged but variable of integration (dx) not

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation

Is it possible to get a tractable expression for

$$\int \ln(x) f(\ln(x)) \:dx$$

Especially interested in situation where $f()$ is the normal density function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=e^y$ and solve
$$\int ye^y f\left(y\right) dy$$